# Girl calling "Dad" to a friend? What does this mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, slang

I'm reading comic books from the 60's, I happen to be in the middle of **The Amazing Spiderman**. In this particular issue Peter Parker and Mary Jane are having a conversation:

> -Tell me M.J, Don't you ever stop to catch your breath?
>
> -Like why, Dad?

**REAL QUESTION**

Why does she call him "dad"? Isn't it weird?

[image]

Here's another conversation from another issue where she calls him dad.

[image]

Comment: Unless _Dad_ is also one expression for _baby_ _love_ or _sweetheart_, then she refers to him as her dad, I admit being interested in this question, I'm very curious about it

Comment: @DavydDiniz I'd thought about it, but in these issues they've met just recently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's slang, and not current slang.

The girl has a beatnik style: straight hair worn down, a black dress with no ornaments. These point to the beat sub-culture of the 50s and 60s.  [Daddy-o](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/daddy-o) was used by "beatniks" or "hipsters" in the 50s and 60s as a general term of endearment towards a man. "Dad" could be seen as an adaptation or shortening. The rest of her language is similar: "Don't worry [...] Lady!", "Tiger", "You're the end!" are all beatnik jargon.

It may also suggest that she views Peter as being a "square" (A socially conventional or conservative person). He acts like a dad, by cutting his hair short, and wearing a tie.

This is not current slang, don't use unless you are trying to sound dated.